# What does the expression "ee" used in Google Earth Engine mean?

Tags: google-earth-engine

What does the expression "ee" used in Google Earth Engine mean?

For example:

`ee.Filter()`

`ee.Geometry()`

`ee.image()`

Because in these examples I can use everything without the term "ee", for example: `Filter()`, `Geometry()`, `image()`, etc.

I would like to know when I should use it, is there any reference to these more primitive terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the name of the client library in programming languages like JS and Python, see: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install.

You can use GEE without the ee prefix depending on where you're using the code. Sounds like whatever development environment you're using has implicitly declared your use of ee. I assume you're coding within the GEE platform? If you're going to use GEE in any kind of non-GEE native script, for instance [using Jupyter](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/ee-api-colab-setup.ipynb#scrollTo=65RChERMzQHZ) notebook, you're going to have to import the GEE Python library:

```
import ee
```

And then call the GEE module content using the ee prefix. If your current environment allows you to either use the prefix or not, with no discernable difference, I would just use it as you don´t know when you need to expose your code to a workflow where your use of GEE isn't being declared implicitly.